# Metodo recursivo para saber si un elemento pertenece a un array, ¿que me falta?

Tags: java

Esto es un método que estoy tratando de hacer de manera recursiva para saber si un elemento pertenece a un arreglo.

```
public static boolean pertenece(int v[], int n, int elemento) {

    boolean pert = false;
    if (n == v.length) {
        return pert;
    }
    if (v[n] == elemento) {
        pert = true;
        return pert;
    } else {
        pertenece (v, n + 1,elemento);

        return pert;
    }
}
```

Comment: y que problema tienes? Te falla? Da una excepción? Por favor, incluye más datos para que podamos ayudarte. Puedes ver [ask] para saber como hacer una pregunta de "calidad". También puedes echarle un vistazo a [tour] para que conozcas un poco más el sitio y su funcionamiento.

Comment: creo que el codigo esta mal pues siempre me devuleve false y creo que es por el ulimo return pero e intentado reestructurarlo y no me funciona

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, recuerda hacer el [tour] puedes ganar algunas medallas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el `else` tienes que retornar el resultado de la llamada recursiva ya que ahora estas devolviendo `false` siempre

```
public static boolean pertenece(int v[], int n, int elemento) {

    boolean pert = false;
    if (n == v.length) {
        return pert;
    }
    if (v[n] == elemento) {
        pert = true;
        return pert;
    } else {
        return pertenece (v, n + 1,elemento);
    }

}
```

Comment: Agradecido, recien acabo de registrarme en el sitio, no lo conocia, estoy en primero de informatica en cuba saludos y otra vez gracias

Comment: De nada. Un placer.